Finding the interval and radius of convergence of a power series with an alternating term
The series in question is:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}\left[2 + \left(-1^n\right)\right]x^{n - 1}
$$

I tried applying ratio test: However, I will still end up with alternating terms in the fraction.
From my understanding, in order for the series to converge, the limit to infinity of the absolute value of
$$
\frac{\phantom{-}2 + \left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{2 + \left(-1\right)^n}\
\frac{\phantom{-}\left(x+1\right)^{n-1}}{\:\left(x+1\right)^n}\quad
\mbox{must be less than}\ 1.
$$
While I could not get rid of the alternating terms ?: The solutions have the interval of convergence as $\left(-2, 0\right)$.
My question is, does that not ignore all terms before
$$
{\phantom{-}\left(x+1\right)^{n-1} \over \left(x+1\right)^{n}}\ ?
$$

In that case, why would the conditions for convergence according to the ratio test still apply ?.




Apply the root test. $(2+(-1)^{n})^{1/n} \to 1$.

$\displaystyle -1^{n} = \color{red}{\LARGE -1}$

As per the hint given to us, put
$$L=\sqrt[n]{|3|}.$$
This becomes
$$L=3^n$$
Take an $n$root to apply root test and you’ll see it tends to $1$ as $x\to\infty$.
So the series is….??
Rest inconclusive…maybe write the sum as:
$\frac{-x-3}{x(x+1)(x-1)}$. This occurs when $|x|<1$. And your interval is $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$. Hope this helps!!!
